# solicitud AJAX tarda mucho en regresar información

Tags: sql, ajax, sql-server, asp

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web usando AJAX, envió un dato a otra pagina que lo procesa para hacer una consulta a una BD, generalmente se devuelven 100 registros y el tiempo aproximado desde que se envía la solicitud hasta la repuesta es de un minuto, se me hizo mucho tiempo de espera, ¿Que puedo hacer para acelerar mas la respuesta ya que me piden que no tarde mucho?

**Solicitud AJAX**

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {       
           
        $("#btnEnviar").click(function() {

        var datos ={fechaTae : $("#fechaTae").val()};
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "buscaTae.asp",
              data: datos,
              success: function(resultado) {           
              document.getElementById("muestraTae").innerHTML = resultado;

              }
              
              });               
        });
    });
```

**Consulta SQL**

```
SELECT a.id, a.tramite, a.movimiento, a.monto, a.fecha, a.cliente as cliente,
    a.nombre, a.operativa, a.poliza, a.pedido, a.rechazo, a.observaciones,
    a.usercreate,a.datecreate,a.userupdate, a.dateupdate, a.comentario, a.tipo, 
    a.presencial, a.Inactivo, a.useroracle, a.emergente, a.vip, b.id AS id2, 
    b.id_sol, b.tipo as tipoo, b.numero as numero, b.monto AS monto, b.aplicar, 
    b.datecreate,c.folio as telcel,c.datecreate as envio 

        FROM Sol_deposito_v2 a, Solicitud_lineas b,folios_tae_v2 c 
        WHERE a.id = b.id_sol and ((LEN(numero)='10' and substring(numero,1,3)
     <> '722') or (LEN(numero)<='5' and a.operativa <> '142')) and 
    b.id=c.id_solicitud and convert(varchar,c.datecreate,103)='"&fecha&"' 
    order by c.datecreate
```

Comment: porque en la consulta sql los int los pones entre comillas, como por ejemplo (LEN(numero)='10'  LEN(numero)<='5'? len es una función que devuelve un int. Que motor de base de datos utilizas?

Comment: uso sql server, entonces van sin comillas?

Comment: claro. Y si el campo  (a.operativa <> '142') es de tipo entero. también va sin comillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un Principio debes arreglar un poco la consulta sql, los int se deben comparar con int, porque sino sql hace una conversión interna por cada operación para poder comparar, y demora. Por otro lado me gusta mas usar Joins para que el código sea mas legible. Por ultimo para que Sql no pierda tiempo evaluando el orden de los joins agregaremos OPTION(FORCE ORDER). Seguramente esto agilizara los tiempos.

```
SELECT a.id, a.tramite, a.movimiento, a.monto, a.fecha, a.cliente as cliente,
    a.nombre, a.operativa, a.poliza, a.pedido, a.rechazo, a.observaciones,
    a.usercreate,a.datecreate,a.userupdate, a.dateupdate, a.comentario, a.tipo, 
    a.presencial, a.Inactivo, a.useroracle, a.emergente, a.vip, b.id AS id2, 
    b.id_sol, b.tipo as tipoo, b.numero as numero, b.monto AS monto, b.aplicar, 
    b.datecreate,c.folio as telcel,c.datecreate as envio 
FROM Sol_deposito_v2 a
inner join  Solicitud_lineas b on  b.id_sol=a.id
inner join folios_tae_v2 c on c.id_solicitud= b.id and convert(varchar,c.datecreate,103)='''' +@fecha +''''
WHERE  ((LEN(numero)=10 and substring(numero,1,3)
     <> '722') or (LEN(numero)<=5 and a.operativa <> '142'))  
 order by c.datecreate
 OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Comment: bien gracias @Ariel Octavio D'Alfeo